# How can I suppress warnings in NetBeans 6.9.1?

Tags: javafx

On teaching JavaFX, we use some older files containing Swing components. They run OK in NetBeans 6.8, but in NetBeans 6.9.1 many following warnings are generated:

**warning: [warnonuse] Package javafx.ext.swing has been used.
import javafx.ext.swing.SwingToggleButton;**

Is there any way to suppress generation of these warnings?

Answer (score 1):

In the desktop.properties file under your JavaFX SDK profiles directory,
you can change the property 
`swing_compile_opts="-XDwarnOnUse=javafx.ext"`
to `swing_compile_opts=`

Under Netbeans this would be in
NETBEANS_HOME/javafx/javafx-sdk/profiles.

This only applies to 1.3.1 and most likely will be totally different in the next
major release of JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jim.  That does the trick.

For Mac users, you have to go into your **/Applications/Netbeans/Netbeans 6.9.1.app** folder, then down to

```
Contents/Resources/NetBeans/javafx/javafx-sdk/profiles.
```

I modified the desktop profile and after restarting Netbeans the warnings went away.